# can't pass value to the input fied in test case

Tags: testing, groovy, automated-tests, spock, geb

I would like to pass a value to the input fied, in the test case. however this is not working. Below is my code.

```
   class Mypage extends Page {
    static content = { 

       inputfield { withFrame ("myFrame") {$('input',name:'myInputField') } 

    }
   }
 }
```

Then tested it this way:

```
given:
    String thevalue = "hello"
then:
    to Mypage
and:
    inputfield >> thevalue
```

With this code I get the

> > StaleElementReference error and the chrome driver information

I then  tried the following by putting the thevalue variable in Mypage class:

```
class Mypage extends Page {

      public  String thevalue = "hello"

      static content = { 

           inputfield { withFrame ("myFrame") 
{$('input',name:'myInputField') } 


    }
   }
 }
```

Then tested it the same way with no given:

```
then:
    to Mypage
and:
    inputfield >> thevalue
```

I Still get the same error.

I then tried a third form:

```
class Mypage extends Page {

      //public  String thevalue = "hello"

      static content = { 

           inputfield { withFrame ("myFrame") 
{ thevalue -> $('input',name:'myInputField').value(thevalue ) } 


    }
   }
 }
```

Then tested it in 2 ways:

```
then:
    to Mypage
and:
    inputfield("hello")
```

and this way:

```
then:
    to Mypage
and:
    inputfield >> "hello"
```

The only way which is working is when I pass the value directly in the class

```
         inputfield { withFrame ("myFrame") 
{  $('input',name:'myInputField').value("hello") }
```

But the goal is to the pass the value in the test. How do I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to follow Rushby's suggestion and stick to the path you shown in your question then the following will work:

```
class Mypage extends Page {
    static content = { 
        inputfield { thevalue ->
            withFrame ("myFrame") { 
                $('input',name:'myInputField').value(thevalue) 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
then:
    to Mypage
and:
    inputfield("hello")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please suggest a document on geb. Because the gebsh.org does not really give much details on a lot of things.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a more comprehensive resource than the Book of Geb from gebish.org. Which things in particular do you believe are missing details in the Book of Geb? Feel free to create issues about missing pieces of documentation in the bug tracker and they will get added.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the Geb example from [The Book of Geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/) you have your page and it contains an iframe.  The iframe in the example has its own page object:

```
class PageWithFrame extends Page {
    static content = {
        myFrame(page: FrameDescribingPage) { $('#frame-id') }
    }
}

//This is your iframe page object
class FrameDescribingPage extends Page {
    static content = {
        myTextField { $('input',name:'myInputField') }
    }
}
```

Now to interact with it, you do this within your test method:

```
def "my test method"() {
when: 
   to PageWithFrame
   withFrame(myFrame) {
       myTextField.value("whatever")
   }
   //etc
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have seen that approach. Geb documentation also says that you can use modules. I prefer using a module for the frame, since it more suitable to the case. The frame is passed between pages and I do not want to use pages for that. I have set the frame as base in the module.